# Is it possible to open screen on core module from activity or class in android module in Libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am developing a game that uses google maps. I have made my game to check the availability of internet connection. 
So, when there is no internet connection , there is offline mode for the game which works very fine but when there is internet connection, 
game displays specific place with the help of google maps. I have kept markers on the place that needs to be shown on maps. And i want to 
open game screen when i click on markers on the maps. Code for google map is in Android module and screen is in core module. 
Can anyone help me out how can i open screen when i click on markers using the method provided by google maps which is as follow:

```
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {};
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have researched about it but i am not able to find the suitable refrence for it. So is it possible to do this or it is not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to change `Screen` from `android` module.

`core` module is injected in all platform specific module so you can access all Class/Interface in any module.

Only you need reference of `Game` class object and an object of new Screen so keep reference of `Game`'s child object in `AndroidLauncher` class.

```
MyGdxGame gdxGame;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
     gdxGame = new MyGdxGame();
     View gameView = initializeForView(gdxGame, config);

     setContentView(gameView);
}
```

Now you've reference of `MyGdxGame`, You can change screen inside `AndroidLauncher` class by calling `setScreen(Screen screen)` method of `Game` class.

```
 gdxGame.setScreen(new MenuScreen());
```

`MyGdxGame` and `MenuScreen` are in `core` module

`MyGdxGame` class

```
public class MyGdxGame extends Game {

    @Override
    public void create() {
        setScreen(new MainScreen());
    }
}
```

`MenuScreen` class

```
public class MenuScreen extends ScreenAdapter {


}
```

**EDIT**

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
       Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 gdxGame.setScreen(new MenuScreen());
            }
        });
     return false;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Your question **Is it possible to change screen from android module**,
I am not focusing on another part of your game so make it simple as possible so I tested with only four classes.

1. `GdxTest`

   ```
   public class GdxTest extends Game{

      @Override
      public void create() {
          setScreen(new FirstScreen());
      }
   }
   ```
2. `FirstScreen`

   ```
   public class FirstScreen extends ScreenAdapter {

     @Override
     public void render(float delta) {

         Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
         Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,1,1);
     }
   }
   ```
3. `SecondScreen`

   ```
   public class SecondScreen extends ScreenAdapter {

      SpriteBatch batch;

     @Override
     public void show() {
         batch=new SpriteBatch();
     }

     @Override
     public void render(float delta) {

       Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
       Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,0,0,1);
     }
   }
   ```
4. `AndroidLauncher` inside android module

   ```
   public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {

      GdxTest gdxTest;
      boolean swap;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          gdxTest =new GdxTest();
          initialize(gdxTest);
     }

     @Override
     public void onBackPressed() {
         Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 swap=!swap;
                 gdxTest.setScreen(swap?new SecondScreen():new FirstScreen());
           }
       });
     }
   }
   ```

Each time when I press back on android device, screen changes from one to another (*this changes from android module*), It sure that, this is possible to change screen from android module.

Comment: Everythins is working well and i am stuck at this point now. There is already a screen using setScreen(new MenuScreen()); method inside my Game class and what i want is to set another screen when google markers are clicked. And inside @Override public void create() method it does not allow to do that because there is already setScreen() present. So, is there any other way i can set screen of my choice?

Comment: I set `MainScreen` from `MyGdxGame`, so Game Start with `MainScreen` now when I want to set/change other screen, let's suppose I want to set MenuScreen from `AndroidLauncher` class so I just called  `gdxGame.setScreen(new MenuScreen());` inside `onMarkerClick()` method

Comment: Here comes the new error, when i click on marker, my game crashes giving following error, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error compiling shader. And it points to the line batch=new SpriteBatch(); in class AbstractScreen();      What causes this error? And what can be the probable cause in case of my game??

Comment: public abstract class AbstractScreen implements Screen {

    public Game game;
    public Viewport viewport;
    protected Stage stage;
    public SpriteBatch batch;
    protected AssetManager assetManager;

    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;
    public AbstractScreen(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
        batch = new SpriteBatch();  camera = new OrthographicCamera(Constants.WORLD_WIDTH, Constants.WORLD_HEIGHT);
        camera.position.set(Constants.WORLD_WIDTH / 2, Constants.WORLD_HEIGHT / 2, 0f);

Comment: `AbstractScreen` is an abstract class and you can't create an object of abstract class, I've edited my answer, please check

Comment: Not yet @AbhishekAryan

Comment: did you tested it? I have tried it for 2-3 day and its not working at all. But its giving more and more errors.lol